# Why doesn't JProfiler show any socket activity

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using a JProfiler evaluation license to profile a client application that writes data to a socket.  I connect successfully to the client after starting it and click on Record Probe Sockets.  The Time Line tab  shows two vertical red lines for when the application starts and terminates.  The Sockets tab shows nothing though.

I know data is being written to a socket because I see the data on the server.  The client uses multiple threads to write data to the socket.

Is there something else I need to do to profile socket usage with JProfiler?  What I really want to see is how much time my application is using to write to the socket and how much time it is blocked while waiting to write to a socket.

Answer (score 0):

The profiler can make event-based and sampling-based measurements. Event-based measurements are only available for classes that are not part of the `java` packages, since it modifies classes on the fly while they are loaded. So, your socket operations are measured by sampling.

Sampling works the way that the profiler inspects stack traces every particular period of time and see what code does (in your case, looks if it is socket operation). Default sampling rate is 5 ms. I would offer to decrease the rate and see if it helps, since your socket operations might be 1 ms long and they are never shown: the profiler stops every time when there is no any socket operation.

Edit: Plus, I would check that sockets profiling is enabled in the first place

Comment: Thanks for that.  Socket profiling is enabled, but I couldn't find where to decrease the sampling period in the GUI.  Also, there is nothing in the doc about socket profiling.  Is it documented somewhere else?

Comment: Try Session Settings -> Profiling settings -> Method call recording. Switch to (if it is not selected) Sampling. Adjust the number of milliseconds

Comment: Did you try to play with JEE & Probes -> Built-In probes -> Sockets settings?

Comment: I switched to Sampling and reduced the time to 1 ms.  Still shows nothing.  I couldn't find an Sockets Settings item.

Comment: There is a vertical profiling settings tab, which you found. On the same level, there is vertical JEE & Probes tab (on the left)